# CompareGroups package in R

Tags: r, comparegroups

I have a dataset with 100 columns and 4 groups.

I want to apply `compareGroups` function to have descriptive and inferential statistics for my data.

However; `compareGroups` function is taking a formula as follows: `compareGroups`(Grouping variable~variable1+variable2..and so on). what would be the code to use `compareGroups` for the whole 100 columns without specifying name of each and every column in my dataset?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`compareGroups(Grouping variable ~ ., data = dataframe)`

The `.` refers to all other ("explanatory") variables.

Please note that `compareGroups` performs a univariate analysis with the dataframe between group (“response” variable) and all other variables (“explanatory” variables).

For more information see the [compareGroups vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/compareGroups/vignettes/compareGroups_vignette.html).

Comment: Can one define a group on the fly? For instance if there are 35 group variables but you want to reduce it to binary. For example, does this work, `compareGroups(groupvariable == "ASRI" ~., data = dataframe)`